# Issue while fetching values in java forEach loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, java-8

I have one list where it may has maximum 2 values OR minimum 0 values. Now I need to set the first item value and second item value to my pojo class.

```
List<student> studentList  = studentRepository.findById(idval);


studentList.forEach(student -> {

            st.setStartTime(student.getStartTime()); // fetch from 1st item
            st.setEndTime(student.getEndTime()); // fetch from 1st item
            st.setNextStartTime(student.getStartTime()); // fetch from 2nd item
});
```

Here I need to set values to my `studentList` pojo. In that pojo I need to set 3 attributes where first two attribute values are from the 1st item of the list and the third attribute value is from the 2nd item of the list.

Can anyone suggest some good way to do the same.

EDIT:
I have a list (studentList) which has two student class object items. (Lets assume the list has studentA and studentB information). Now I need to iterate the studentList and set the values to one pojo (st). In the `st` pojo I have 3 attributes are there. here I need to set the first two attribute values with studentA information and the third attribute value with studentB information.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some details? It's unclear ...

Comment: updated my question with Edit

Comment: Why are you overwriting st with the second student's data? Why not just get the second student from the list? Or are you trying to cater for the 1-student case?

Comment: Why do you say you "need to iterate" when in fact you just want to get specifically the 1st and 2nd elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I could do for index foreach is by using `Intstream`

```
List<student> studentList  = studentRepository.findById(idval);

IntStream.range(0, adpodList.size()).forEach(index -> {
            if(index == 0)
            {
 st.setStartTime(studentList.get(index).getStartTime()); // fetch from 1st item
 st.setEndTime(studentList.get(index).getEndTime()); // fetch from 1st item
}
else if(index == 1)
            {
st.setNextStartTime(studentList.get(index).getStartTime()); // fetch from 2nd item
}});
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that this isn't a suitable candidate for iteration - you're not doing the *same* thing with each element in the collection and, further, you've got a different behaviour for the 'empty collection' case than for the 'not-empty collection' case.

I'd go with this...

```
List<student> studentList  = studentRepository.findById(idval);
if (studentList.size() == 2) {
    st.setStartTime(studentList.get(0).getStartTime()); // fetch from 1st item
    st.setEndTime(student.get(0).getEndTime()); // fetch from 1st item
    st.setNextStartTime(student.get(1).getStartTime()); // fetch from 2nd item
}
```

It's more expressive than a loop or a collection transformation, because you're not really trying to do either.

Caveat:- you probably want to handle `size() == 0`, `size < 2` and `size > 2` cases as well, unless you can get your Repository to return a collection type that truly makes that size guarantee for you.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
for (int i=0 ; i<studentList.length-1 ; i++) {
    Student next = studentList.get(i+1);
    studentList.get(i).setNextStartTime(next.getStartTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you have maximum 2 values, you could check `if(studentList.size()>1)` there are 2 values and set the values of `st` with `studentList.get(0)` and `studentList.get(1)`.

I hope it helps.